# does python BaseHttpServer support Html5?

Tags: python, http, html

I am using BaseHttpServer of Python-2.6.6. I could not make it work with  tag. Does Python-2.6 really support HTML5 ?

This could be more helpful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 617, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 329, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 323, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "testServer.py", line 43, in do_GET
    self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 357, in send_error
    self.send_response(code, message)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 382, in send_response
    (self.protocol_version, code, message))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 318, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Server Side:

```
if self.path.endswith(".ts"):           
    f = open("simpsons.ts", 'r')
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'video/mpegts')
    self.end_headers()      
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
    return
```

Client Side:

```
video width='320' height='240' src="simpsons.ts" controls="controls" /video
```

Image Code(Working):

Server Side:

```
if self.path.endswith(".png"):          
    f = open("ps_logo2.png", 'r')
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'image/png')
    self.end_headers()      
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
    return
```

Client Side:

```
img src="ps_logo2.png" alt="No Image"/
```

Comment: what does HTML5 has to do with HTTP?

Comment: Define _"could not make it work"_ please.

Comment: I am trying to use Video tag in my html. With the video tag GET request, Python giving: error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe on server side. Where as with image tag, its working absolutely fine.

Comment: post some code so we can look at it

Comment: Very funny that you deduce a HTML5 problem from a "broken pipe" error. HTML5 doesn't have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: The traceback says `'File Not Found``. Make sure that `f = open("simpsons.ts", 'r')` works. Though I might not be sufficient to the video to play.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 support lives at the browser level primarily, not at the language level. So yes, Python does support HTML5 implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have misdiagnosed your problem. HTML5 is entirely browser side. The broken pipe is indicative of something else.